# Independence of the Axiom of Separation

Tags: set-theory

Consider ZFC with the Axiom of Replacement formulated as
$$ \forall x\forall y\forall z(\phi(x,y)\land \phi(x,z)\to y=z) \to \forall a\exists w\forall x\forall y(x\in a\land \phi(x,y)\to y\in w) $$
where $\phi$ is a two-place predicate that may contain parameters not among $a, x, y, z, w$. The difference from the usual Replacement is that it may produce a *superset* of the range of $\phi$.

For my purposes here, ZFC includes the Axiom of Regularity, and the null set, pairing, union, and power set axioms do give exact results.

In the presence of the Axiom of Separation, the weakened Replacement axiom easily implies the exact version; conversely the full Replacement by itself implies Separation.

However, the weak Replacement does not seem to imply Separation. Is there a nice way to prove this?

More precisely, let FC be ZFC as sketched above, *without* Separation. Does ZFC prove that FC is consistent?

---

If we didn't have to satisfy Regularity, it would be easy: Let the universe be $\mathbb N$, and let $n\in m$ mean "$m=0$ or the $n$th bit in the binary representation of $m-1$ is `1`". Then $0$ would represent a universal set, which would immediately satisfy the weakened Replacement as well as Infinity. But this model would fail Regularity due to the universal set (and its singleton). And without a universal set it seems to be hard to be sure you've tamed *all* possible instances of the weak Replacement.

Comment: I looked at Fraenkel etal. Foundations of set theory for this and in a footnote on page 53 they say that this is an unpublished result of Levy that uses forcing. I have no idea what Levy's model could have been.

Comment: Also see page 75 here: http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/20.pdf and the references mentioned there

Comment: Do say if you think my answer is wrong or unclear! I'd be more than happy to find out what I'm missing or to clarify.

Comment: @hot_queen: Nice reference, thanks. It does imply a negative answer to "does FC prove Separation?", but not to "is there a nice proof or this?" or "does ZFC prove the consistency of FC?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following class-sized model in ZFC works, I think. (And I would guess that a set-sized version could be constructed in ZFC).

Let:

$\mathcal M_0 = \emptyset$

$\mathcal M_{\alpha+1} = \mathcal M_\alpha \cup\{\mathcal M_\alpha\}\cup \{\{x,y\}:x,y \in \mathcal M_\alpha\} \cup \{\cup x:x\in\mathcal M_\alpha\}\cup\{\{y\subseteq x: y\in \mathcal M_\alpha\}:x\in\mathcal M_\alpha\}\cup \{y\subseteq \mathcal M_\alpha\cap x\times x: x\in\mathcal M_\alpha \wedge \mbox{$y$ is a well-order of $x$}\}$

$\mathcal M_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} \mathcal M_\alpha$

It is easy to see that $\mathcal M_\Omega = \bigcup \mathcal M_\alpha$ satisfies Infinity, Pairing, Union, Foundation, and Choice. For Powerset, note that the subsets of $x$ have to all occur in some $\mathcal M_\alpha$. Similarly for Replacement.

Now a simple induction establishes that the transitive closure of every set in $\mathcal M_\Omega$ either contains finitely many finite ordinals or infinitely many non-ordinals. So it does not contain $\omega$, even though $\omega$ is $\Delta_0$ definable over $\mathcal M_\omega = V_\omega$.

Comment: What really interests me here is what hides inside the quick claim "Similarly for Replacement". Why can you be sure that the range of an arbitrary functional formula $\phi$, when interpreted relative to the full $\mathcal M_\Omega$, will always fall within one of the $\mathcal M_\alpha$s?

Comment: We just use Replacement in the ambient theory. Let $\phi$ be functional in $\mathcal M_\Omega$ and let $\psi$ map each thing in the range of $\phi$ to its rank in $\mathcal M_\Omega$. By Replacement, there will be a least upper bound of those ranks, $\lambda$, and the range of $\phi$ will be a subset of $\mathcal M_\lambda$.

Comment: Hmm... and $\phi$ relativized to $\mathcal M_\Omega$ is still functional in the ambient theory, so the outer Replacement does apply. Okay, I'll buy that.

Comment: Right! (Well, technically $\phi^{\mathcal M_\Omega}(x,y) \wedge y\in\mathcal M_\Omega$ is functional, not necessarily $\phi^{\mathcal M_\Omega}$)

Comment: @HenningMakholm Any other concerns? Just let me know!

Comment: Naw, just holding out to see if someone comes up with a set-sized model to settle whether ZFC proves Consis(FC) too.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Cool. I'm tempted to think that $\mathcal M_{\omega_1}$ might work; in particular, that one might be able to argue that the subsets of $x\in\mathcal M_{\omega_1}$ have to be exhausted by some countable stage. But I don't have time to think this through at the moment.